# TypeError when SQLAlchemy engine.connect tries to compare MS SQL Server version

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm on a Windows OS and Python 3.6.4 and I'm trying to connect to an InterSystem ODBC35 DSN Datasource using SQLAlchemy 1.2.5.

Using pyodbc to connect to the DSN Datasource works great but when using the SQLAlchemy `create_engine` method:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@mydsn", echo=True)
cnxn = engine.connect()
rows = cnxn.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.tables").fetchall()
print(rows)
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-03-29 11:33:44,631 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
2018-03-29 11:33:44,631 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mentrix.py", line 28, in <module>
    cnxn = engine.connect()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2102, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2188, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 345, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 784, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 532, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1189, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1186, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 350, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 477, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 677, in __connect
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 274, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 284, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 1334, in go
    return once_fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 183, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1931, in initialize
    super(MSDialect, self).initialize(connection)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 267, in initialize
    self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1958, in _get_default_schema_name
    if self.server_version_info < MS_2005_VERSION:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you try changing the line 1958 in the file `C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py` to `if int(self.server_version_info) < int(MS_2005_VERSION):`? If that works, I'll have a little bit more digging to do and issue a patch.

Comment: nothing changed.. just a different error message:
`  File "C:\Users\m.m\Envs\mentrix\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1958, in _get_default_schema_name
    if int(self.server_version_info) < int(MS_2005_VERSION):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: Is "InterSystem ODBC35" meant to be compatible with MS SQL Server? An honest and possibly silly question. It'd seem that the version info is not what was expected by the SQLA mssql dialect.

Comment: @IljaEverilä it is compatible. it works with other systems BUT NOT with SQLAlchemy :/ and it works perfectly with pyodbc.connect()

Comment: It seems that an issue was opened: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4227/sql-server-pyodbc-allows-non-int-tokens-in